# Pandas to_sql returning error due to column names with sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I'm trying to store stock screens in an sqlite database but when I use screen.to_sql() from pandas it returns:

```
Error: near "/": syntax error
```

If I replace all the slashes with ' over ' then I get the following:

```
Error: unrecognized token: "]"
```

I'm confused because this code is nearly identical to the one I used for a mysql database, can anyone see why sqlite does not like this?

Here is the full query as created by pandas.

```
CREATE TABLE raw_screens (
              [Company_Name] TEXT,


[Ticker] TEXT,
  [%_Ratio_of_Q1/prior_Yr_Q1_Actual_Q(-3)] TEXT,
  [Price/Book] TEXT,
  [Price/Sales] TEXT
  [Current_ROE_(TTM)] TEXT,
  [Current_ROI_(TTM)] TEXT,
  [ROI_(5_Yr_Avg)] TEXT,
  [Current_ROA_(TTM)] TEXT,
  [ROA_(5_Yr_Avg)] TEXT,
  [Market_Value/#_Analysts] TEXT,
  [Annual_Sales] TEXT,
  [Cost_of_Goods_Sold] TEXT,
  [EBITDA_] TEXT,
  [Price/Cash_Flow] TEXT,
  [PEG_Ratio] TEXT,
  [P/E_(F2)] TEXT,
  [%_Ratio_of_Q1/Q0] TEXT,
  [This_Yr`s_Est.d_Growth_(F(1)/F(0))] TEXT,
  [Last_Yrs_Growth_(F[0]_/_F_[-1])] TEXT,
  [%_Change_EPS_(F(-1)/F(-2))] TEXT,
  [Long-Term_Growth_Consensus_Est.] TEXT,
  [5_Yr._Hist._EPS_Growth] TEXT,
  [Sales_Growth_F(0)/F(-1)] TEXT,
  [5_Yr_Historical_Sales_Growth] TEXT,
  [F(1)_Consensus_Sales_Est._(Mil.)] TEXT,
  [Q(1)_Consensus_Sales_Est._(Mil.)] TEXT,
  [P/E_(Trailing_12_Months)] TEXT,
  [EBIT_] TEXT,
  [Pretax_Income_] TEXT,
  [Preferred_Equity] TEXT,
  [Current_Liabilities_] TEXT,
  [Long_Term_Debt_] TEXT,
  [Current_Assets_] TEXT,
  [Intangibles] TEXT,
  [Inventory_] TEXT,
  [Receivables_] TEXT,
  [Debt/Total_Capital] TEXT,
  [Debt/Equity_Ratio] TEXT,
  [Current_Ratio] TEXT,
  [Quick_Ratio] TEXT,
  [Book_Value] TEXT,
  [Asset_Utilization] TEXT,
  [Inventory_Turnover] TEXT,
  [Net_Income_] TEXT,
  [Cash_Flow_] TEXT,
  [Net_Income_Growth_F(0)/F(-1)] TEXT,
  [12_Mo._Net_Income_Current/Last_%] TEXT,
  [12_Mo._Net_Income_Current-1Q/Last-1Q_%] TEXT,
  [5_Yr_Div._Yield_%] TEXT,
  [5_Yr_Hist._Div._Growth_%] TEXT,
  [Dividend_] TEXT,
  [Net_Margin] TEXT,
  [Operating_Margin_12_Mo] TEXT,
  [Turnover] TEXT,
  [Cash_Ratio] TEXT,
  [Rank_in_Industry_(of_ABR)] TEXT,
  [%_Price_Change_(YTD)] TEXT,
  [%_Price_Change_(4_Weeks)] TEXT,
  [%_Price_Change_(1_Week)] TEXT,
  [Beta] TEXT,
  [Price_as_a_%_of_52_Wk_H-L_Range] TEXT,
  [Last_Close] TEXT,
  [Current_Avg_Broker_Rec] TEXT,
  [%_Rating_Strong_Buy_or_Buy] TEXT,
  [%_Rating_Strong_Sell_or_Sell] TEXT,
  [Industry_Rank_(of_ABR)] TEXT,
  [52_Week_Low] TEXT,
  [%_Price_Change_(12_Weeks)] TEXT,
  [Relative_Price_Change] TEXT,
  [Q0_Consensus_Est._(last_completed_fiscal_Qtr)] TEXT,
  [52_Week_High] TEXT,
  [Market_Cap_] TEXT,
  [Last_EPS_Surprise_(%)] TEXT,
  [P/E_(F1)] TEXT,
  [%_Rating_Change_-_4_Weeks] TEXT,
  [%_Change_F1_Est._(4_weeks)] TEXT,
  [Div._Yield_%] TEXT,
  [Avg_Volume] TEXT,
  [Shares_Outstanding_] TEXT,
  [Change_in_Avg_Rec_] TEXT,
  [%_Rating_Hold] TEXT,
  [%_Change_Q2_Est._(4_weeks)] TEXT,
  [%_Change_Q1_Est._(4_weeks)] TEXT,
  [%_Change_F2_Est._(4_weeks)] TEXT,
  [%_Change_LT_Growth_Est._(4_weeks)] TEXT,
  [Q1_Consensus_Est._] TEXT,
  [St._Dev._Q1_/_Q1_Consensus] TEXT,
  [Q2_Consensus_Est._(next_fiscal_Qtr)] TEXT,
  [St._Dev._Q2_/_Q2_Consensus] TEXT,
  [F0_Consensus_Est.] TEXT,
  [F1_Consensus_Est.] TEXT,
  [St._Dev._F1_/_F1_Consensus] TEXT,
  [%_Change_Q0_Est._(4_weeks)] TEXT,
  [12_Mo_Trailing_EPS] TEXT,
  [Last_Reported_Fiscal_Yr_] INTEGER,
  [%_Rating_Upgrades_] TEXT,
  [%_Rating_Downgrades_] TEXT,
  [Common_Equity] TEXT,
  [Average_Target_Price] TEXT,
  [Previous_EPS_Surprise_(%)] TEXT,
  [Avg_EPS_Surprise_(Last_4_Qtrs)] TEXT,
  [Actual_EPS_used_in_Surprise_($/sh)] TEXT,
  [Last_Qtr_EPS] TEXT,
  [Last_Reported_Qtr_] TEXT,
  [Last_Yr's_EPS_(F0)_Before_NRI] TEXT,
  [F2_Consensus_Est.] TEXT,
  [Date] TEXT

                  );
```

Comment: is this the cause: [This_Yr`s_Est.d_Growth_(F(1)/F(0))] TEXT it looks like this maybe escaping the string

Comment: Taking care of both the / and the ` we end up with 
  [This_Yr's_Est.d_Growth_(F(1)_over_F(0))] TEXT,
but it still returns the error concerning the ]. Thanks though!

Comment: I'd do a divide and conquer to find the offending column line, so remove half the columns, parse again, if it succeeds, try the other half, on failure keep halving until you find the line. Fix it and restart again

Comment: I'll probably just make a quick python screen to try to make a table with each line individually. Thanks!

Comment: even `"` may break now depending on the database backend, I have created an issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9393) and the fix is to properly quote and escape things. Actually the issue is about table names, but similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` quotes cannot be nested.

You should use a quote character that can be escaped, such as `"` (which would have to be doubled):

```
...,
"my silly name" TEXT,
"my even ""sillier"" name with quotes" TEXT,
...
```

(In this case, you don't even have `"` in the names.)